# Laravel request User with related table

Tags: laravel, roles, inertiajs, laravel-permission

I am quite new to this but I hope I can get some help or explanation how to solve my problem.

How could I request a User with a related table already included in the result?
For example, I have the User model and Roles model. How can I automatically include Roles when requesting User. I am using Spatie Roles and Permissions.

I can do `User::with('roles')->get();` but how could I include roles with this request `Request $request->user();`

```
return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
        'auth' => [
            'user' => $request->user(),
            'role' => $request->user()->getRoleNames(),
        ],
    ]);
```

If I request them separately then role gets added to auth and also user has role relation available.

I have HasRoles included in my User model.

I would like to have Roles "attached" to the User model when I request it to be available everywhere and I wouldn't have to request Roles separately. I am using inertiajs, so I want the roles to be included with the authenticated user.

Comment: Is [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default) what you're looking for?

Comment: You want to get the user role name?

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI Thank You! This was exactly what I wanted! I had to add `protected $with = ['roles'];` to my model.